# Run time for a specific loop confusion

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have a loop:
`for(int i = 1; i < N; i*=5) {...}`

where `{...}` is some statement.

I'm trying to understand its run time. So, far I know that:

- We start with $i = 1$
- We finish when $i > n$
- $i$ is incremented by being multiplied by 5.

So, would the run-time be $\log_5(n-1)$? The reason I'm not sure it's because I thought when analyzing algorithms we had to use base 2 log functions. If the latter is the case how would I got about converting $\log_5$ to $\log_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic result in elementary arithmetic states that
$$
\log_a n = \log_a b \cdot \log_b n.
$$
Indeed, on the one hand, $a^{\log_a n}$ by definition. On the other hand,
$$
a^{\log_a b \cdot \log_b n} = (a^{\log_a b})^{\log_b n} = b^{\log_b n} = n.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\log_b n = \log_b a \cdot \log_a n.
$$
This shows that every two logarithms only differ by a constant multiple. Since big O notation discounts constant factors, it doesn't matter which logarithm you use (unless it's in the exponent). For example, a function is $O(\log_a n)$ iff it is $O(\log_b n)$. For this reason we usually don't bother writing the basis of a logarithm in big O notation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you intended to write, but your loop runs in constant time if N <= 0, and will never finish if N > 0.

If you start with i = 0, and multiply i by 5, guess what: It's still 0. I really can't see how you get to $i^5$. After k iterations, the initial value of i is replaced with $i * 5^k$; since the initial value is 0, it stays 0, and the loop never exits if N > 0.

If you started with i = 1, it would be extremely unlikely that you would ever get i = N-1. For example, the loop will exit with i = 3,125 with the last iteration i = 625 for all 625 < N ≤ 3,125. Only when N is one larger than a power of 5 will i ever equal N-1 (if we start with i = 1).

Comment: I meant for `i` to start with one and you're right with `i `finishing in `n-1` is highly unlikely. I will edit my question appropriately.